# How to pass select values to a POST request in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

There is a form, which is filled in the View. The `ProductModel` is attached to the View.

All fields are filled out successfully.

The problem is how to pass dynamically added data along with them to `select`. They have `Value` and `Name` values.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult New(
        ProductModel product,
        IFormFile upload,
        [Bind("Name")] CharacteristicParameters productCharacteristic
)
{
    // Here's how to work with the data 
}

public class CharacteristicParameters
{
    public IEnumerable<string> productCharacteristic { get; set; }
}
```

The HTML code is as follows:

```
    <select 
        class="form-select" size="5" name="productCharacteristic"
        aria-label="..." id="productCharacteristicList">
    </select>
```

Of course it is inside:

```
    <form asp-action="New" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"> 
        ...
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
    </form>
```

At first I tried adding the

```
public SelectList productCharacteristic { set; get; }
```

field to the model itself. Unfortunately, this option passed empty data.

Also considering the use of

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> productCharacteristic { set; get; }
```

or

```
List<string> productCharacteristic { set; get; }
```

None of them produced the desired result.

After a long time of analysis and trying other attempts, I tried to use the creation of another model `CharacteristicParameters productCharacteristic` containing `public IEnumerable<string> productCharacteristic { get; set; }` and use Bind.

Already thought about at least pulling just string values.

Unfortunately, an object `null` is still returned to the controller.

Comment: I don't understand if your Product has just one characteristic or you have a product and want to set more than one characteristic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example form:

```
<form method="post">
    <input asp-for="Name" type="text" placeholder="Name" />
    <select name="dynamicValues" multiple>
        <option value="test">Test</option>
        <option value="test 5">Test 1</option>
        <option value="test 7">Test 2</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Post</button>
</form>
```

when you click submit

http post payload:

```
{
  name:'Okan',
  dynamicValues:test,
  dynamicValues:test 5
  
}
```

model binding should be in .net

```
public User { public string Name {get; set;}}

public UserPost(User user, List<string> dynamicValues)
```

if you want access name in selectlist, access on value

```
var name = selectList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == "test");
```

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, it works. However, I noticed that the main error was the unselected elements. There is no way to pass absolutely everything (highlighted and unselected)?

Comment: you could access by `var unSelecteds = selectList.Where(x => !dynamicValues.Contains(x.Value)).ToList();`